# How to make Rails's four directories "fonts, images, scripts and stylesheets" displayed in Safari's page resources?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web, safari, web-development-server

Rails version: 3.2.21

When I run a project [vish](https://github.com/ging/vish), when accessing "http://localhost:3000" and open Safari's "show page source" there are four directories `fonts, images, scripts and stylesheet` in the left-side as following picture viewed:

[image]

When I built my own rails app project based on the same platform, there is no directories except files under `localhost`:

[image]

What should I do for such effect? What options should I config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `config/environments/development.rb`, there is a option called `assets.debug` , whose default value is `false`, If you want to see all the above directories you should change the value into `true`:

```
# Expands the lines which load the assets
config.assets.debug = true
```